# Trait `Borrow<String> is not implemented for `&str`

Tags: rust

I am trying out some examples in the `The Rust Programming Language` book, and have the following code snippet:

```
fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, i32, RandomState> = HashMap::new();
    let hello: String = String::from("hello");
    map.insert(&hello, 100);
    println!("{:?}", map); //{"hello": 100}
    let first_hello_score: Option<&i32> = map.get("hello"); // This compiles
    let hello_score: Option<&i32> = map.get(&hello); // This does not compile
}
```

On running `cargo check`, I see:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: Borrow<String>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:26:27
   |
26 |     let hello_score = map.get(&hello);
   |                           ^^^ the trait `Borrow<String>` is not implemented for `&str`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Could someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`.get` looks for `&Q` as the parameter, where the key type `K` is `Borrow<Q>`. Since there's a blanket implementation that borrows `&T` into `&T`, `&str` (the key type) can be borrowed into `&str` (the argument type)

However, when doing `&hello`, you actually have an `&String`, which means Rust infers `String` to be `Q`, so it tries to borrow `&str` into `&String`, which is obviously not possible. So, be **explicit** about the deref coercion so that Rust knows it should deref the `&String` into `&str`:

```rust
let hello_score: Option<&i32> = map.get(&hello as &str);
```

Or,

```rust
let hello_score: Option<&i32> = map.get(&*hello);
```

Comment: Shouldn't deref coersion take care of &String -> &str?

Comment: get() is a generic method. Without a type parameter, the type of key is determined to that of the value passed to the method. In order to activate deref coercion, a call for the method should be ```HashMap::<&str, i32>::get::<str>(&map, &hello)```